# Abstract Class from UML to ER diagram. Possible ? How?

Tags: mysql, uml, entity-relationship

I have the below UML class diagram with Abstract Class, and sub-Classes that extends from it. and i want to make an ER diagram using this class diagram.

[image]

My question is how can i represent the Abstract class in ER diagram ? as a Table ? or should i just ignore it ?

Thank you.

Comment: To be honest it looks the same with out . see the examples here where you can also make an erd online https://online.visual-paradigm.com/drive/#diagramlist:proj=0&new=ERDiagram  also look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191228/is-erd-considered-a-kind-of-uml-diagram

Comment: You might also have a design flaw here. What if a teacher is also an Admin? In your design that is not possible. I think you should separate Users from the roles they play.

Comment: @GeertBellekens No that's not the case here. I already know that one user can either be an Admin, Teacher or a student

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are basically three choices to translate generalization into a database model

### 1. One table per concrete class

Create tables `Admin`, `Teacher` and `Student`. Each of these table contain columns for all of the attributes and relations of `User`

- Pro

  - All fields of a concrete subclass are in the same table, so no join needed to get all Student data
  - Easy data validation constraints (such as mandatory fields for `Student`)
- Con

  - All fields of `User` are duplicated in each subclass table
  - Foreign keys to `User` have to be split into three FK fields. One for `Admin`, one for `Teacher` and one for `Student`.

### 2. On table for whole generalization set

In this case you just have one table call `User` that contains all fields of `User` + all fields of all sub-classes of `User`

- Pro

  - All fields are in the same table, so no join needed to get all `User` data
  - No splitting of FK's to `User`
- Con

  - There are a bunch of fields that are never used. All fields specific for `Student` and `Teacher` are never filled in for `Admins` and vice versa
  - Data validation such as mandatory fields for a concrete class such as `Student` become rather complex as it is no longer a simple `Not Null` constraint.

### 3. One table per concrete class, and one for the superclass

In this case you create tables for each of the concrete sub-classes and you create a table for the class `User`. Each of the concrete sub-class tables has a mandatory FK to `User`

- Pro

  - Most normalized schema: No repeated fields for the attributes of user, and no unused fields.
  - No splitting of FK's to `User`
  - Easy data validation constraints (such as mandatory fields for `Student`)
- Con

  - You have to query two tables if you want all data of a `Student`
  - Complex validation rules to make sure each `User` record has exactly one `Admin`, `Teacher` or `Student` record.

Which one of these options you choose depends on a number of things such as the number of sub-classes, the number of attributes in either subclass or superclass, the number of FK's to the superclass, and probably a few other things I didn't think about.

Comment: I've accepted your answer since it enlights me to search more on this, and as you said these are the only 3 methods to perform generalization. As a result, i've chosen the 3rd method as it works well for my requirements (not that it is the best method).,